# Multiple Inputs and Outputs ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have a large number of IP cameras, I can access each through the RTSP protocol. 
I want to use ffmpeg to convert RTSP to MJPEG  each camera.

I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://xxxx/h264 http://localhost:8090/INPTU1.ffm -i rtsp://xxxx:554/h264 http://xxx/INPUT2.ffm
```

But the command repeat  each output with the  first input.

My web application should display each camera in the network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you need to do is run multiple FFmpeg processes.  One for each camera.

Comment: I tried doing this, but on reaching 20 cameras all goes very slow. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you expect to happen with 20 cameras?  And, you think that cramming everything in a single process would help?  Processing video is very resource intensive.  You need some beefy hardware to handle it, not to mention the bandwidth needed for 20 streams of videos.  Are you sure you need to display each individual camera stream in your application?  You can't create a composite view, or reduce the resolution?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is not necessary to show all the videos at the same time, my idea is to make a streaming video that is requested at that time. 
I've thought about video on demand, I tried to use nginx, but I failed, attempt to convert the IP camera (rtsp) to rtmp without success.